# SonarQube: "Store a copy of "productAllergenInfos""

Tags: java, sonarqube, dto, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I have the following DTO:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MenuItemExpandedDTO {
private UUID uuid;
private List<ModifierGroupDTO> modifierGroupDtoList;
private List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList;

public MenuItemExpandedDTO(
        PropertiesDTO propertiesDto,
        List<ModifierGroupDTO> modifierGroupDtoList,
        List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList
) {
    this.uuid = propertiesDto.getUuid();
    this.modifierGroupDtoList = modifierGroupDtoList;
    this.allergenInfoList = allergenInfoList;
  }
}
```

In SonarQube analysis, I get a Vulnerability due to `allergenInfoList` as it is stated

*"Message: Store a copy of allergenInfoList"*

So, I am not sure what the problem is, but before fixing this error, I am wondering what is wrong with that code? In some pages, it is recommended to initialize the list e.g. `private List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList = Collections.emptyList()`. But it is not a way I follow in my projects. So, what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Sonarqube should give you a reference to the rule, providing more detail. This one may be https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube is telling you to be cautious when receiving `List`s in a constructor. Why? Because the caller holds a reference to that `List` and it can do the following with it if it is not immutable:

1. Change the `List` content by adding or removing elements to it, actually affecting your `MenuItemExpandedDTO`.
2. Change the objects contained in the `List` if they are not immutable. This means that `AllergenInfo` objects in the `List` can be changed affecting your `MenuItemExpandedDTO` object.

To tackle 1., you can simply store a copy of the `List` as SonarQube suggests:

```java
public MenuItemExpandedDTO(
        PropertiesDTO propertiesDto,
        List<ModifierGroupDTO> modifierGroupDtoList,
        List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList
) {
    this.uuid = propertiesDto.getUuid();
    this.modifierGroupDtoList = new ArrayList<>(modifierGroupDtoList);
    this.allergenInfoList = new ArrayList<>(allergenInfoList);
  }
}
```

Tackling 2. is trickier and the simplest and more reliable solution is to use immutable objects. You can read more about this and how to design your classes so that you have immutable objects at https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object.

```java
public class MenuItemExpandedDTO {
    private final UUID uuid;
    private final List<ModifierGroupDTO> modifierGroupDtoList;
    private final List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList;

    public MenuItemExpandedDTO(PropertiesDTO propertiesDto,
                               List<ModifierGroupDTO> modifierGroupDtoList,
                               List<AllergenInfo> allergenInfoList) {
        this.uuid = propertiesDto.getUuid();
        this.modifierGroupDtoList = new ArrayList<>(modifierGroupDtoList);
        this.allergenInfoList = new ArrayList<>(allergenInfoList);
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return UUID;
    }

    public List<ModifierGroupDTO> getModifierGroupDtoList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(modifierGroupDtoList);
    }

    public List<AllergenInfo> getAllergenInfoList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(allergenInfoList);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `ModifierGroupDTO` and `AllergenInfo` must also be immutable so that `MenuItemExpandedDTO` is 100% immutable.

Comment: **1.** Thanks a lot for your good explanations. I have never used such a kind of usage e.g. `this.modifierGroupDtoList = new ArrayList<>(modifierGroupDtoList)`, I generaly use `this.modifierGroupDtoList = new ArrayList<>()`. So, what is the meaning of `this.modifierGroupDtoList = new ArrayList<>(modifierGroupDtoList)`? I think it is meaning that, assign `modifierGroupDtoList` to `this.modifierGroupDtoList`. Is that true?

Comment: Would you suggest Tackling 2 over Tackling 1 as mentioned on https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object ?

Comment: It assigns a new `List` containing the content of `modifierGroupDtoList` to `this.modifierGroupDtoList`, so that you have a different list than the one provided (only the list, not the objects inside it). This means that you have to tackle both 1. and 2. if you want to be 100% sure that no one else messes with the `List`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. Could you also provide an example by using the code in my answer to show **Tackling 2**?

Comment: Done. Please check my edited answer ;)